# Why this :not() instruction isn't working?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I try to select all `li`s in the page except whose are inside a container(ascendant) with class .foo

Output: The li `22` should not be colored.

I can't use direct descendants because there could be nested lis and uls.

[image]

Comment: how about `body :not(.foo)  li ` ?

Comment: `body :not(.foo) li` not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess css selectors are using an `OR` or `ORELSE` relation. So when you use a selector like `:not(.foo) li` something similar happens:

`statement1`: In first place it will check: is actual element's tagname is `li`? (`true`)
`statement2_1`:In second place it will check: is closest parents class not `.foo`? (`true`)
`statement2_2`:In next place it will check next parent: is next parent class not `.foo` (`false`)

Theoretically the following statement evaluates:
`statement1 AND (statement2_1 ORELSE statement2_2)`
`true AND (true ORELSE false) => true AND true = > true`

What if you just try other way:

```css
li{
  background-color: red;
}

.foo li{
  background-color: initial;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>11</li>
</ul>
<div class=foo>
  <ul>
    <li>22</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not correct. The `:not` pseudo-class can be used by itself, it doesn't have to be attached to another selector. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot

Comment: Like Guffa said, the not class can be used by itself, and the first ul isnt inside any div. I need to select any container.

Comment: Sorry, You're right. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Yeah I found the logic of CSS reading the RFC. Your answer is correct now. I must used the alternative.

Comment: There is no OR relation. The `:not(.foo) li` selector is evaluated by first matching the element against `li`, and if that matches checking if it has a parent element that matches `:not(.foo)`. As the closest parent `ul` matches that, it will never consider the `div`.

Comment: You've said almost the same, just with other words.  
(s stands for statement)  
s1: `element is li `  => `true`  
s2: `element's parent is :not(.foo)` => `true`  
s3: `element's other parent is :not(.foo)` => `false`  
   
I said: `s1 AND (s2 OR s3)`  
You said: `s1 AND (s2 ORELSE s3)`

Answer (score 2):

It's not working because you haven't specified that it's that exact element that can't have the class. The `ul` element that contains the `li` element doesn't have that class, so that matches the `:not(.foo)` part of the selector.

Make sure that the `:not(.foo)` part applies only to the right element, for example by specifying exactly where the element is in relation to the list element:

```css
:not(.foo) > ul > li { background: red; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>11</li>
</ul>
<div class="foo">
  <ul>
    <li>22</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't use direct descendants because the code is dynamic, there could be nested lis and uls.

Comment: @DocKodam: Then you can use any other way to specify where the element is. If they for example are directly in the `body` element (as in the example) you can use `body > :not(.foo) li`.